# How do I use SDL_PeepEvents properly?

Tags: c, sdl

When I call the function *PeekEvents* below the program prints zeros on the standard output and never finishes even though I type on the keyboard when the SDL window has focus. Why doesn't the function catch my keystrokes?

```
void PeekEvents(void)
{
    SDL_Event events[1];
    int count;

    do {
        count = SDL_PeepEvents(events, LEN(events), SDL_PEEKEVENT, SDL_EVENTMASK(SDL_KEYDOWN));
        printf("%d\n", count);
    } while (count == 0);
}
```

Here is the complete program:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(a) ((int) (sizeof (a) / sizeof (a)[0]))    

static void PeekEvents(void)
{
    SDL_Event events[1];
    int count;

    do {
        count = SDL_PeepEvents(events, LEN(events), SDL_PEEKEVENT, SDL_EVENTMASK(SDL_KEYDOWN));
        printf("%d\n", count);
    } while (count == 0);
}


static void Init(int *error)
{
    SDL_Surface *display;

    *error = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    if (! *error) {
        display = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 8, 0);
        if (display != NULL) {
            *error = 0;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "SDL_SetVideoMode: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            *error = 1;
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_Init: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        *error = 1;
    }   
}


int main(void)
{
    int error;

    Init(&error);
    if (! error) {
        PeekEvents();
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to init Events in SDL_Init, SDL_INIT_EVENTS.

Comment: @dohashi As far as I understand the event mechanism is initialized with SDL_INIT_VIDEO. The function SDL_PollEvent works as expected. By the way, I use SDL 1.2 which doesn't define SDL_INIT_EVENTS.

Comment: Did you try SDL_ALLEVENTS?

Comment: @2501 SDL_ALLEVENTS is not defined in SDL 1.2 (http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlinit.html).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Did you try it, you will notice it is defined.

Comment: @2501 I'm a bit confused. If I initialize SDL with all bits set (0xFFFFFFFF) it works but if I use SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING (0x0000FFFF) it doesn't work. Is there an undocumented subsystem that need to be initialized in order for the SDL_PeepEvents function to work?

Comment: @2501 You're right about SDL_ALLEVENTS being defined but it's not documented. However, I don't want to get all events from SDL_PeepEvents, only keypresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation states somewhere that SDL_INIT_EVENTS is implicit when using SDL_INIT_VIDEO.

You need to add a call to SDL_PumpEvents in your loop, otherwise no messages will ever get in the queue.

SDL_PumpEvents gathers all the pending input information from devices and places it on the event queue. Without calls to SDL_PumpEvents no events would ever be placed on the queue. Often the need for calls to SDL_PumpEvents is hidden from the user since SDL_PollEvent and SDL_WaitEvent implicitly call SDL_PumpEvents. However, if you are not polling or waiting for events (e.g. you are filtering them), then you must call SDL_PumpEvents to force an event queue update.

Comment: Thank you very much Gunther. Adding `SDL_PumpEvents();` just before the SDL_PeepEvents call did the trick.